# What is the connection between LocationRequest object and LocationChangeListener

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I have been following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html) for my application that needs to get current location updates even if 10 steps are walked, or maybe every 2 minutes, but I think time based would be more demanding in terms of battery usage, in the begning documentation says:

> your app specifies the required level of accuracy/power consumption and desired update interval, and the device automatically makes the appropriate changes to system settings. These settings are defined by the LocationRequest data object.

what does it mean? accuracy level, and update interval?

After that when its explaining these things they say

> To store parameters for requests to the fused location provider, create a LocationRequest. The parameters determine the level of accuracy for location requests.

does it mean that we can get current location update like updated latlng with setInterval()? if so then why we have to use onlocationchangelistener? if requirement has been fulfilled by location request

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is exactly two main terms about location, these are

- Getting last known location (old location)
- Receiving location updates (fresh location)

Understanding the those terms will help in the relation between LocationRequest and it's listener.

**Getting last known location**

The location api can give the last obtained location for given provider, without location request. This location could be obtained at any time for example 3 - 5 hours ago and by an app(including yours). There is no need to say 'hey provider please give me fresh location', so we don't need LocationRequest object.

**Receiving location updates**

This is where we need to say 'hey provider please give me fresh location at every 30 seconds with high accuracy'

To define our above request, we need to create LocationRequest object.

To receive result of our request, we need to create listener(receiving process is asynchronous)

This is the relation between LocationRequest and listener.

---

LocationRequest object is used for two purposes

1. As mentioned above, to make location request for fused provider
2. To prompt a dialog to make adequate requirements of location request(for example level of accuracy)

Comment: what about if we walk 10 steps, will onlocationchanged call?

Comment: Not step or walk, its actually location change in meters. If you set for example 10 meters,  it will provide you the changes by meters.  As a result the listener will be called.

Comment: Okay, what about if i move my phone from one room to another will there be change in latlng of device?

Comment: And thank you, please answer my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995445/how-to-get-real-time-current-location-update-as-we-walk

Comment: Yes it can but rarely,  because receiving location updates a bit hard indoor places. For best result it must be working outdoor.